# Unable to connect Spring AMQP / Rabbit MQ : org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am new to Spring AMQP / Rabbit MQ.

Am using a Spring AMQP / Rabbit MQ in my project. I am facing following error after running a tomcat:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer
>   - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it.
>
> Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Below is the configuration file :

### spring-amqp.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="127.0.0.1"/>
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:template connection-factory="connectionFactory" id="rabbitTemplate" channel-transacted="true"/>
    <rabbit:queue name="proposalQueue" />

    <rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
        <rabbit:listener ref="listener" queue-names="proposalQueue"/>
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="rabbitMQTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.transaction.RabbitTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="myExchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
             <rabbit:binding queue="proposalQueue" key="userMesssage" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
    <bean id="listener" class="com.xxx.xxxx.rabbitmq.QueueServer"/>
 </beans>
```

### QueueServer.java

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();       
    MessageProperties props = message.getMessageProperties();
    BasicProperties replyProps = new BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(new String(message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId())).build();
    String inputParameterStr = new String(message.getBody());

        try {
            Map<String,Object> inputParameters  = (Map<String, Object>) Utility.StringToObject(inputParameterStr, "java.util.Map");
            result = service.createQueue(inputParameters);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Error :::: "+getClass()+proposalID, e);
            result.put(Constants.FAILURE, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error :::: "+getClass()+proposalID, e);
            result.put(Constants.FAILURE, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 19):

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

That simply means that RabbitMQ is not running on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) on the standard port (5672).

Did you download and install/run RabbitMQ? It is not like ActiveMQ - it can't run embedded in a java application.

Comment: Yes. RabbitMQ (3.5.6) and ERLANG (otp_win32_18.1.exe) is installed on c:.  Status of RabbitMQ  service is start.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not listening on port 5672 (the default). Try `netstat -ano | find "5672"` in a `cmd` window; if it's actually listening, you should see `127.0.0.1:5672 ... LISTENING`. Look at the rabbitmq logs to see if there is information there.

Comment: thanks..I checked it on cmd but there in no any listening port as you said : **127.0.0.1:5672** and please tell me the path where log is generated. Rabbit mq is running on 25672 (Check in resource monitor.)

Comment: I am not familiar with rabbit on Windows; sorry; but it looks like there's a problem with your installation; according to [this link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html), 25672 is used for clustering so it is strange that it is listening but not 5672; you need to find where the logs are and look at them. If all else fails; there's a google group rabbitmq-users for questions about rabbitmq itself (don't ask questions about spring-amqp there, though; this is the right place for that.)

Comment: Thanks Gary.. I re-install the Rabbitmq using link which you give. still it use 25672 port and error is same. On another machine same procedure is followed for installation and all is done well..

Answer (score 8):

Check the host and port value

In application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

[image]

See RabbitMQ site is running on port 15672 whereas in code using amqp protocol.

Comment: RabbitMQ AMQP is not the same RabbitMQ Management. They are indeed running on different ports

Answer (score 2):

*There's one more aspect to the problem*.

By default, the RabbitMQ is accessible to the local machine only. If you want to access it from some other machine, you generally create one entry in "rabbitmq.config" file. Location of this file varies from OS to OS. In Linux, you can find this at: "**/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config**" and in Windows machine, you can find it at: "**C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\etc\rabbitmq.config**".

There's a possibility that you don't find this file at the mentioned location. This is an optional file and you need not to worry if it is missing even. You can create your own.  This entry is something like:

```
[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"<IP_OF_MACHINE>", 5672}]},{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

With this, you can access the server from any remote machine.

If after this you get the server inaccessible you can modify the entry to:

```
[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5672}]},{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

You will *definitely* get the server connected to any client as well as through management console (if plugin enabled)

Answer (score 1):

i'm confronted the same problem (when using docker). Above answers didn't help me. I switched to a different version rabbitmq.

was:

```
rabbitmq:3.9.14-management-alpine
```

now:

```
rabbitmq:3.9.8-management-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the RabbitMQ remote , you need to allow inbound TCP traffic on ports 4369, 25672, 5671, 5672, 15672, 61613, 61614, 1883, and 8883.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=4369/tcp --add-port=25672/tcp --add-port=5671-5672/tcp --add-port=15672/tcp  --add-port=61613-61614/tcp --add-port=1883/tcp --add-port=8883/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue coz my rabbitmq container was not running

Answer (score 0):

For those who using Docker and got java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, in additional to port 15672 in docker-compose, **you need to add 5672 port**.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.10.7-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
```

After that the exception disappeared